# Изменение значения глобальной переменной в локальной среде не считывается

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Значение глобальной переменной `currentLength` изменяется через введение в `input` разных значений. Нужно, чтобы значение глобальной переменной `currentLength` было равно текущему значение в input. При введении числа 120 должен сработать `alert`, он не срабатывает, что означает, что значение глобальной переменной не переопределяется. Как сделать, чтобы оно переопределялось всё-таки?

```js
function getCurrentLength(){
  let currentLength = 0;
  let output = document.getElementById('output');
  
  calcLength();
 
  function calcLength() {
    let total = +output.value;
    let len = document.getElementsByClassName('len');
    for (let i = 0; i < len.length; i++) {
      len[i].addEventListener('input', function() {
        let value = 0;
    currentLength = +len[i].value;
        for (let j = 0; j < len.length; j++) {
          let num = +len[j].value || 0;
          value += num;
        }
        output.value = total + value;
      })
    }
  }
 
  if(currentLength === 120) {
   alert(currentLength)
  }

}
getCurrentLength();
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input {
  width: 170px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="length" class="len">
<input type="text" placeholder="length" class="len">
<input type="text" placeholder="length" class="len">
<input type="text" placeholder="length" class="len">
<input type="text" placeholder="length" class="len">
<input type="text" id="output" placeholder="output">
```

Значение глобальной переменной `currentLength` изменяется через введение в `input` разных значений. Нужно, чтобы значение глобальной пременной `currentLength` было равно текущему значение в `input`.

```js
let currentLength = 0;
let output = document.getElementById('output');
console.log(currentLength)
calcLength();

function calcLength() {
  let total = +output.value;
  let len = document.getElementsByClassName('len');
  for (let i = 0; i < len.length; i++) {
    len[i].addEventListener('input', function() {
      let value = 0;

      for (let j = 0; j < len.length; j++) {
        let num = +len[j].value || 0;
        value += num;
        currentLength = +len[i].value;
      }
      output.value = total + value;
    })
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input {
  width: 170px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="length" class="len">
<input type="text" placeholder="length" class="len">
<input type="text" placeholder="length" class="len">
<input type="text" placeholder="length" class="len">
<input type="text" placeholder="length" class="len">
<input type="text" id="output" placeholder="output">
```

Comment: А у вас разве оно не равно текущему значению?

Comment: Все работает. О чем вопрос?

Comment: Переменная currentLength должна быть равна текущему значению в input, а она равна 0 (см.консоль). Да. Не совсем корректно описал проблему... Исправил в описании.

Comment: в примере происходит вывод в консоль до какого-либо изменения переменной.

Comment: Ну и засунь ее в функцию, что бы она динамический менялась

Comment: Нет. Она должна быть вне функции, т.к. потом её значение берётся для расчёта последующих переменных в составе ещё бОльшей функции.

Comment: Мне кажется ты не совсем понимаешь как работает `JS`

Comment: Да. Я в начале пути изучения js. Тут только ошибками опыта и набираться. Иначе никак(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У переменной меняется значение, просто этого не видно

```js
let currentLength = 0;
let output = document.getElementById('output');
console.log(currentLength)
calcLength();

function calcLength() {
  let total = +output.value;
  let len = document.getElementsByClassName('len');
  for (let i = 0; i < len.length; i++) {
    len[i].addEventListener('input', function() {
      currentLength = +this.value;
      console.log(currentLength) // изменения

      let value = 0;
      for (let j = 0; j < len.length; j++) {
        let num = +len[j].value || 0;
        value += num;
      }
      output.value = total + value;
    })
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input {
  width: 170px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="length" class="len">
<input type="text" placeholder="length" class="len">
<input type="text" placeholder="length" class="len">
<input type="text" placeholder="length" class="len">
<input type="text" placeholder="length" class="len">
<input type="text" id="output" placeholder="output">
```

Comment: Т.е. я всё сделал правильно, по сути, только с консолью запутался, да?)))))))) Сам себя надурил))

Comment: Ага...))))))))))